# Extracting point data from a large shape file in R

Tags: r, gis, shapefile, r-maptools

I'm having trouble extracting point data from a large shape file (916.2 Mb, 4618197 elements - from here: https://earthdata.nasa.gov/data/near-real-time-data/firms/active-fire-data) in R. I'm using `readShapeSpatial` in `maptools` to read in the shape file which takes a while but eventually works:

```
worldmap <- readShapeSpatial("shp_file_name")
```

I then have a `data.frame` of coordinates that I want extract data for. However R is really struggling with this and either loses connection or freezes, even with just one set of coordinates!

```
pt <-data.frame(lat=-64,long=-13.5)
pt<-SpatialPoints(pt)
e<-over(pt,worldmap)
```

Could anyone advise me on a more efficient way of doing this?

Or is it the case that I need to run this script on something more powerful (currently using a mac mini with 2.3 GHz processor)?

Many thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By 'point data' do you mean the longitude and latitude coordinates? If that's the case, you can obtain the data underlying the shapefile with:

```
worldmap@data
```

You can view this in the same way you would any other data frame, for example:

```
View(worldmap@data)
```

You can also access columns in this data frame in the same way you normally would, except you don't need the `@data`, e.g.:

```
worldmap$LATITUDE
```

Finally, it is recommended to use `readOGR` from the `rgdal` package rather than `maptools::readShapeSpatial` as the former reads in the CRS/projection information.